# Duplicate/Copy an alias to "Applications" folder in Mac using Applescript

Tags: duplicates, copy, applescript, alias

I am able to make an alias of an executable on the desktop using this code -[How to change icon of alias created using applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898756/how-to-change-icon-of-alias-created-using-applescript)

I want to copy/duplicate the alias to a folder inside the Applications directory ,
so I tried as follows
`duplicate newAlias to folder "myFolder of folder Applications of startup disk"` but it times out.

I'm a newbie to Applescript , so I'must be making some simple mistake.

What is the right way to do this ?

Note: I want to retain the same name of the alias at the copied destination

Comment: Are you really using the system Applications folder, and do you have permissions to write to the destination?  Is there a particular reason for the alias file in so many locations?

Comment: Ok I was able to do it this way duplicate newAlias to folder "Macintosh HD:Applications:myFolder" but will this be compatible for older versions of Mac like EI Capitan ? I'm using High Sierra right now

Comment: I don't have an El Capitan machine to test, but it should work as long as you have write permissions for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on High Sierra and El Capitan as well

```
duplicate newAlias to folder "MyFolder" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
```